# Getting phantomjs 1.9.8 to render borders round HTML table cells in PDF correctly

Tags: pdf, phantomjs, html-table

Rendering a table, with boarders, to PDF using phantomjs leaves each individual cell bordered but with a gap between each cell. The table is displayed correctly, without such gaps, on a web page.

in my CSS I've tried setting:

```
border-collapse: collapse;
border-spacing: 0px 0px;
```

to no avail, I need to get rid of those gaps between cells in my PDF.
Any ideas would be gratefully received.
Yours Allan

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to add the `border-spacing` and `border-collapse` rules to the `<table>` and not the `<td>`. This is my phantomjs-specific rules:

```
.table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-spacing: 0px 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.table th,
.table td {
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Note that this is a bit different than 'normal' (not phantomjs-pdf) css where your border-collapse can be located on the `<td>` element.

Comment: Thanks  `border-collapse: collapse;` at the 'table' level did the trick.